# I need help in wring QTP script to read and write data from/in Excel

Tags: excel-2007

I have a excel workbook name prog.xls in D:\
in sheet1 i have 3 column contains n number of records with first row as a column heading 
column1-Name,Column2-DOB,Column3-Email_Id.
I want to match DOB to current date to check whose Birthday is today and want to copy corresponding Email_Id to sheet2.

Below Is My code

```
MyDate=Date
Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")
myxl.Workbooks.Open "D:\prog.xls"
set mysheet = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Row=mysheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i= 2 to Row

If Mysheet.cells(i,2).value =Day(MyDate)&"/"&Month(MyDate) Then
```

above code is working fine,but its not complete. it will only check. but how to store corresponding Email_ID into sheet2. Please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and let me know.

```
MyDate=Date

Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")
myxl.Workbooks.Open "D:\Form.xls"
myxl.application.Visible = True
set mysheet = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Row=mysheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

j=1
For i= 2 to Row

If mysheet.cells(i,2).value =Day(MyDate)&"/"&Month(MyDate) Then
Email=mysheet.cells(i,3).value

set mysheet = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
mysheet.cells(j,1)=Email
j=j+1
set mysheet = myxl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End If
Next
myxl.ActiveWorkbook.save
myxl.quit
Set myxl =Nothing
```

Thanks